# Yandex Disk - RESTApi - Автоматизация процесса получения токена - C#

Tags: c#, яндекс-диск

Стоит задача - автоматизировать на языке C# получение токена в RESTApi YandexDisk.

-Не могу получить токен т.к. мало опыта работы с запросами к внешним ресурсам используя инструменты языка  С#. А там как раз для получения токена используется ссылка типа:

> [https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=идентификатор_приложения](https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

которая уже перенаправляет на указанный в приложении CALLBACK_URL в  адрес перенаправления которого содержиться access_token, что-то типа:

> [http://localhost:1050/tokens/get#access_token=тут_токен&token_type=bearer&expires_in=время_жизни_токена](http://localhost:1050/tokens/get#access_token=%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD&token_type=bearer&expires_in=%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Comment: Иногда бывает полезным заглянуть на [гитхаб](https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=yandex+api&type=Repositories) --- [вот уже написано кое-что](https://github.com/raidenyn/yandexdisk.client)

Comment: @Bulson там, по-моему, про получение токена ничего нет. Я тоже с этой проблемой столкнулся и понятия не имею, как можно было бы получить токен.